# Возврат значения из Observable (Angular)

Tags: javascript, angular

Подскажите почему возвращает Observable, а не массив данных.

Компонент сервиса:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Компонент вызова сервиса из компонента:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Возвращает Observable, хотя по идее должно возвращать массив данных:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Потому что вы rxjs используете... Если нужны объекты то так можно: `... this.searchService.getVideoFromJson(this.searchTitle).subscribe( d => this.obj = d)` и объект будет в this.obj

Comment: Потому что вы возвращаете не массив, а `Observable`, у вас даже в функции тип объявлен `Observable<any>`.

Answer (score 0):

Прочитайте про [Futures and promises pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Futures_and_promises). `Observable` позволяет дождаться асинхронных данных. В данном случае я бы предложил привести `Observable` к `Promise` и применить оператор `await`

```
...

async searchVideo() {
  const result = await this.searchService.getVideoFromJson(this.searchTitle).toPromise();
  console.log({result});
}

...
```

Смысл в том, что `Observable` подразумевает наличие активного http запроса и ожидания (в вашем случае), а не самих данных. Подобная семантика позволяет не прерывать исполнение программы, пока данные качаются из интернета